# How to append the lat and long in an array of dictionary in the interval of 10 milliseconds ?

Tags: ios, swift

I am making an app in which I have to send the lat and long array of dictionary every 10 milliseconds interval . I am doing it like this .

```
   func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,
                                 didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    myLocation = locations.last
    let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate

    currentSpeed = (manager.location?.speed)! as Double
    lat = locValue.latitude  as Double
    lng = locValue.longitude as Double

    var arrayDict = [[String : AnyObject]]
    arrayDict.append["lat":lat , "long" : long]

  }
```

but here I have all the lat and long , I only want to appent elements in the interval of 10 milliseconds.
Thanks all in advance .

Comment: see this http://zaachi.com/2013/09/30/ios-locationmanager-location-update-in-my-own-interval-with-application-in-the-background.html

Comment: Thanks @ Anbu.Karthik

Comment: 1. There's no guarantee you will get location updates at this frequency. 2. Don't know why you need to do that on a client side, but you will kill battery. 3. You can additionally check CLLocation's `timestamp` as a hint to schedule your array 'fill up rate'. 4. Add more context to your question - there can be way better solution :)

Answer (score 1):

take a boolean globally named "locationBool"

```
 var locationBool = Bool()
 var arrayDict = [[String : AnyObject]]
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.10, target: self, selector: #selector(self.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true);
}
func update() {
// Something code
   locationBool = false
}
 func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,
                                         didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) 
    {
        if locationBool == false
        {  
                 locationBool = true
                 myLocation = locations.last
                 let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate

                 currentSpeed = (manager.location?.speed)! as Double
                 lat = locValue.latitude  as Double
                 lng = locValue.longitude as Double


                 arrayDict.append["lat":lat , "long" : long]
                }
            }
```

Comment: var arrayDict = [[String : AnyObject]] . Its ok to initialise within the condition ?

Comment: declare `var arrayDict = [[String : AnyObject]]` in view load

Comment: i update my answer please check it if we declare var arrayDict = [[String : AnyObject]] in view load then we can not access array dic out side thats why we have to declare it globally :)